# Is it possible to dismiss antlions in Half-Life 2?

Tags: half-life-2

I'm replaying *Half-Life 2*, and I got the antlion pheremones/"bugbait" a little while ago. Now I've moved on to a smaller area where my antlion followers are getting in my way more than they're helping me. What's worse, every time one dies, a new one spawns offscreen and rushes in to "help." Is there a way to dismiss them? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't dismiss them to my knowledge, but if they're obstructing your path, you can toss the bugbait behind you to direct them elsewhere.

I also seem to remember that if you press hard enough through them, they'll budge out of your way like any other NPC.  In any case, it's usually best if you direct them forward as much as possible to soak up enemy bullets.

Comment: If you feel trigger-happy you can always kill them if they block your path. They can't become hostile and just re-spawn somewhere else. If you want to preserve ammo then freeman their behinds with a crowbar! EDIT: Also no, there is no way to dismiss them.